# How to get $x$ in terms of $y$ and $w$ from $w = a p x^{p-1} \left(a x^p+b y^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}-1}$

Tags: equation-solving

I'm having trouble to solve the following equation for $x$ both manually and in *Mathematica*:

$\quad \quad w = a p x^{p-1} \left(a x^p+b y^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}-1}$

In *Mathematica* notation:

```
w == (((a (x^p) + b (y^p))^((1/p) - 1))*p*a*(x^(p - 1)))
```

Answer (score 4):

The various powers involving `p` serve to bury the `x` too deep to be able to solve for it without additional assumptions. To make the job of specifying such assumptions easier, I'll introduce an auxiliary variable `z`. First I solve for `z`, which requires only two additional assumptions to allow `Solve` to invert the powers. The result is stored in `zSolution`. Then I recover `x`:

```
Clear[z, w, a, p, b, y];

x = z^(1/p);

zSolution = 
 First@Solve[
   Simplify[
    w == ((((a (x^p) + b (y^p))^((1/p) - 1))*p*a*(x^(p - 1)))), 
    Assumptions -> p > 0 && z > 0], z]
```

> ```
> Solve::ifun :  "Inverse functions are being used by ...
> ```

```
(*
==> {z -> -((b (w/(a p))^(p/(-1 + p)) y^p)/(-1 + a (w/(a p))^(p/(-1 + p))))}
*)

x /. zSolution

(*
==> (-((b (w/(a p))^(p/(-1 + p)) y^p)/(-1 + a (w/(a p))^(p/(-1 + p)))))^(1/p)
*)
```

The reason I chose to replace `x = z^(1/p)` is that the new equation in `z` removes the powers `x^p`, so you have to worry about fewer exponents in the calculation.

If you want to do this manually, it's arguably easier than the *Mathematica* approach as long as you don't worry about the assumptions: You'll notice that if you bring the lone factor `x^(p - 1)` into the large parenthesis, it cancels the `x` that's already there in one term, and adds a `1/x` in the other term. That leaves `x` only in one spot, and you can invert for `x`.

Answer (score 3):

Factor `x^p` out of the last term to get

```
 w == a p (a + b (y/x)^p)^(1/p-1)
```

then use

```
Eliminate[{{w == a p (a + b z^p)^(1/p - 1), z == y/x}}, z]
```

to get

```
((-a + ((a p)/w)^(p/(-1 + p)))/b)^(1/p) == y/x && x != 0
```

$\left(\frac{\left(\frac{a p}{w}\right)^{\frac{p}{p-1}}-a}{b}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\frac{y}{x}\land  x\neq 0$